# Is it possible specify Xamarin Forms Entry Numeric Keyboard without comma or decimal point separator?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have to create a form in which the user must input his age. I would like to use a numeric keyboard:

```
    <Entry
        x:Name="AgeEntry"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Keyboard="Numeric"
    />
```

but it shows even the decimal point character, I'd like to show only numbers...

Comment: You would need to create your own keyboard to make it work across platforms. But you could easily add a trigger that would just erase the comma and decimal as soon as it is typed to prevent the user from using it. Let me know if you want to see that code.

Comment: ...yes, it would be helpful to see that code, i'm very new to xamarin code

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To restrict the `Entry` to only accept numbers you could use a [Behavior](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/creating/) or a [Trigger](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/).

Both of those will react to a user typing into them. So for your use, you could have the trigger or behavior look for any characters that are not numbers and remove them.

Something like this for a behavior (note that I wrote all this on SO and did not try compiling it, let me know if it does not work):

```
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp {

    public class NumericValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry> {

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry) {
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry) {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
        }

        private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args) 
        {

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue)) 
            { 
                 bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x=>char.IsDigit(x)); //Make sure all characters are numbers

                ((Entry)sender).Text = isValid ? args.NewTextValue : args.NewTextValue.Remove(args.NewTextValue.Length - 1);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"> <!-- Add the local namespace so it can be used below, change MyApp to your actual namespace -->

  <Entry x:Name="AgeEntry"
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         Keyboard="Numeric">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <local:NumericValidationBehavior />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @Falco Just tested it out and had an issue with the logic. Try copying the code again if you tried using the previous version.

Comment: Hi, thank you, you are very kind, I can' t find "All()" in ToCharArray(), it does not compile... anyway I understood how bahavior works and changed that line in your code. Anyway I'm new to Xamarin, and I'm surprised some thinks are not built in... best was not to show at all the "point" in the keyboard. I'll study how to create a custom keyboard...

Comment: @Falco Happy to help out. To get `All()` to compile, you will need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the class (I added it in my example code). I will say that creating a custom keyboard could be quite difficult but it is not something I have studied much myself.

Comment: Add filter to NumberDecimalSeparator bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || x == Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));

Comment: thanks, but one thing , that Keyboard="Numeric" not matter , i removed it and it is working properly

Comment: @hosamhemaily Yes, it will work without `Keyboard="Numeric"` but if you are only allowing numeric characters, then there is no reason to display a keyboard that defaults to showing letters.

Comment: @hvaughan3 sorry for asking but if i would like to just additionally besides 0-9 want to allow decimal separator which part of your code has to be changed. Thats first question. Second question. Why if i type dot on keyboard it still going to bindable property?

Comment: I think you would want to edit the call to `All()` and check for periods as well: `.All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || x == '.')`. Not sure I follow your second question. Does it go to the property and then get removed immediately after?

Comment: Do you know how we can set the cursor position to the location of the removed char? For example, say I start with '1234' and then I move the cursor and enter a '.' to get '12.34'. When that gets removed it resets the cursor to the front of the string which is definitely not ideal or what I would think is expected behavior. `CursorPosition` is respected when set in XAML and the view first loads but after that nothing. I can even see its value is different than what's on screen.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I do not have experience messing with cursor position. You may end up needing to go with a custom renderer on each platform to set cursor position after initial rendering. You might also try using the latest version of Xamarin to make sure if was not fixed recently. Otherwise I did find the following link discussing Android custom render for cursor: https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/01/xamarin-forms-get-cursor-position-in.html

Comment: @hvaughan3, thanks for the info. I'm actually doing a test project in MAUI but it seems to be a lingering issue (or feature?) in Xamarin as well. Because MAUI's just in preview and it's an evolution of Xamarin, help I've found on the later has been applicable. I did find a PR that's been merged that supposedly implemented it so maybe it needs an issue raised.

Answer (score 17):

To me the simple solution is just to add a TextChanged handle to the Entry (this is UI specific code so does not break MVVM)

```
   <Entry Text="{Binding BoundValue}" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
```

Then in code behind

```
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //lets the Entry be empty
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue) ) return;

        if ( !double.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out double value) )
        {
            ((Entry) sender).Text = e.OldTextValue;
        }
    }
```

Change in int.Parse if need an integer

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this too, but the best way to implement this is through behaviors, [here is an article](https://doumer.me/xamarin-forms-tips-part-2-numeric-entry-recipes/) which shows you in detail how to implement this and even more, like limiting the value of the number entered to a given value you set in your XAML.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
{
    bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(char.IsDigit);

    ((Editor)sender).Text = isValid ? args.NewTextValue : args.OldTextValue;
}
```

This prevents adding any non digit char into the Editor no matter where you added it.
So if your cursor was in the middle of your number and you got for example 21h3 in @hvaughan3's answer you would just remove the last char giving you 21h with the non digit still being present.

My answer will just use the value you had before adding the non digit char (213).

**But keep in mind!**
If you put this in a behavior and react to editor.TextChanged Event, this is still gonna change the Text for a brief second to the invalid value since this event triggers when it ALREADY was set. this is no OnTextChanging event.
Same for @hvaughan3's answer.
To prevent any issues you might get because of this, for example because you're also listening to OnTextChanged in Code behind, just add this line before working with the new text value

```
if (!editor.Text.All(char.IsDigit)) return;
```

Comment: This is the more complete answer, but still not perfect. when you put a non numeric char in the middle of the string it doesn't get added as expected, but the cursor moves to the end of the string. I've tried fiddling around with getting the cursor position before changing the string and resetting it but haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?